# Comparison between date field and date string php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im doing a search, the search works fine the only part of the query that is giving me problem is when im
 comparing DATE((LiveTrip.TripDate) >= DATE(?)).

It doesnt give me an error, it just doesn't bring back anything i have tested this query using heidi sql and it works. The date is posted in this format YYYY-MM-DD. The field against comparison has a date data type in the db. Any suggestions?

```
 $Limit = $_POST['limit'];
 $Offset = $_POST['offset'];
 $TripType = $_POST['TripType'];
 $datesearch = $_POST['datesearch'];
 $Departure = "%{$_POST['Departure']}%";
 $Destination= "%{$_POST['Destination']}%";

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT
  UsersMain.Id,
  UsersMain.Name,
  UsersMain.Surname,
  LiveTrip.Id,
  LiveTrip.DepstreetAddress,
  LiveTrip.DepSubTown,
  LiveTrip.DestStreetAddress,
  LiveTrip.DestSubTown,
  LiveTrip.SeatsAvailable,
  LiveTrip.TripDate,
  LiveTrip.TripTime,
  LiveTrip.Contribution,
  LiveTrip.Comments
  FROM
  LiveTrip
INNER JOIN UsersMain ON UsersMain.Id = LiveTrip.UserId
WHERE 
LiveTrip.DepSubTown like ? 
AND
LiveTrip.DestSubTown like ? 
AND LiveTrip.TripStatus =1 AND DATE((LiveTrip.TripDate) >= DATE(?)) AND  TripType=? LIMIT ? OFFSET?");

$stmt->bind_param("ssssss",$Departure, $Destination, $TripType,$datesearch,    $Limit, $Offset);

 /* execute query */
 $stmt->execute();

 /* Store the result (to get properties) */
 $stmt->store_result();

 /* Get the number of rows */
 $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

   $stmt->bind_result($id,$Name,$Surname,$Tid,$DepstreetAddress,$DepSubTown,$DestStreetAddress,$DestSubTown,$Seats,$TripDate,$TripTime,$Contribution,$Comment);
```

Comment: Put space between `?` and `like` as in `like ?`

Comment: You dont see any errors because you are not looking for them!!! Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: It does usually throw errors if there is an sql error.

Comment: Aren't your parameters in the wrong order? As far as I can see it should be `...$datesearch, $TripType...`, not `...$TripType, $datesearch...`

Comment: Also, the parentheses are not closed OK in this part of the query: `DATE((LiveTrip.TripDate) >= DATE(?))`

Comment: If `LiveTrip.TripDate` is of type `DATE` and the variable `$datesearch` will contain a string of format `YYYY-MM-DD`, then the comparison should be as simple as: `LiveTrip.TripDate >= ?`. No casting is necessary, just make sure `$datesearch` has the right format.

Comment: Thanks @ Zoli Szabo you were spot on it worked...